# Unable to get the magento version 1.9.3

Tags: magento

Any one here who can share link with me to download the magento version 1.9.3.
I am trying to download this but could't found any source. 
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Magento Download](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) page.

Click on the Release Archive tab.

Scroll down to bottom you will[image] see the details to download Magento 1.9.3